# No parameterless constructor defined for this object error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've written a simple web application to save a record to a database and for that purpose import two models with a tuple in the View in this way:

```
@model Tuple<Web.Models.RequestRegister, Web.Models.interfaceModel>
```

The View code:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRequest", "Default"))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(tuple=>tuple.Item1.Subject)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.RequestType, new SelectList(ViewBag.RequestList, "RequestType", "RequestName"))
        @Html.DropDownListFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.interfacename, new SelectList(ViewBag.interFaceList, "id", "interfacename"))
        <button type="submit">Save User</button>
    }
```

and this is my `SaveRequest` method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveRequest(Tuple<Web.Models.interfaceModel,Web.Models.RequestRegister> model)
        {
            //Database.RequestSave(model.Item2.Subject.Trim(),model.Item2.RequestType,model.Item2.InterFace);
            return View();
        }
```

But when I run the application and fire the submit button, I get this error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
>   constructor defined for this object.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `RequestRegister` and `interfaceModel` tuple position switch between view and controller?

Comment: @Sajal thanks for pay attention to my problem,want send two model to controller

Comment: Hello.. have you got a parameterless constructor on your class called "Description"? This is needed by the framework for the model serialization.

Comment: A  `Tuple` does not have a parameterless construction. You cannot have a `Tuple` as a parameter in a POST method. Use a view model.